# Stochastic interpretation of regularized least squares

Tags: least-squares

I've seen that the regularized LS:
$$ \min_w \| X^Tw-y\|_2^2+\lambda \|w\|_2^2$$
with $\lambda>0$ has also the stochastic interpretation:
$$ \min_w E[\|(X+N)^Tw-y\|_2^2]$$
where $N$ is a random noise matrix with, $E(N) = 0$ and $E(N^TN) = \lambda I$.

I think I got the intuition, but I don't know where to begin to sketch a formal proof.

Answer (score 3):

We can manipulate what you've and obtain the former:
$$\begin{align}E\left[\|(X+N)^Tw-y\|_2^2\right]&=E\left[(X^Tw-y+N^Tw)^T(X^Tw-y+N^Tw)\right]\\&=E\left[\|X^Tw-y\|_2^2+w^TNN^Tw+2w^TN(X^Tw-y)\right]\\&=\|X^Tw-y\|_2^2+w^TE[NN^T]w+2w^TE[N](X^Tw-y)\\&=\|X^Tw-y\|_2^2+w^T\lambda Iw\\&=\|X^Tw-y\|_2^2+\lambda\|w\|_2^2\end{align}$$
However, I've used the fact that $E[NN^T]=\lambda I$, while you state $E[N^TN]=\lambda I$. They're not the same thing. Can you share the source for completeness?